# Единственное или множественное число?

Tags: лексика

В таких выражениях, как:

1. Како**вы** требования и состав (здесь логично, что множ. число)
2. Укажите св**ой** адрес и телефон (здесь по логике напрашивается множ. число, но как-то не звучит).
    Как быть в подобных случаях? Когда единств. число, а когда множ. число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае вопрос касается согласования сказуемого с однородными подлежащими, во втором - согласования определения с несколькими существительными.

**Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным — однородным членам**, ставится в форме единственного числа:

1) если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: российская печать, радио и телевидение; развитие нашей техники, науки и культуры; создание новой оперы, балета, музыкальной комедии; литературный карьеризм и индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина, в своем изложении и выводах…
 **Согласование сказуемого зависит от формы связи между однородными подлежащими.**

Если однородные подлежащие связаны соединительными союзами и, да или только интонацией, то сказуемое обычно ставится в форме множественного числа.
Рассказывать обо всех случаях согласования слишком долго. Скажу только, что в большинстве случаев возможны оба варианта.